# Turn music on and off using a segmented control

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uisegmentedcontrol

I am making a simple game just to learn some iOS development. I have searched the web, youtube and so on but I cant find anything that helps me. I'll try to make this simple.

I have four views:

- [Start Menu View]
- [The Game View]
- [Settings View]
- [How To Play View]

The [Start Menu View] includes [Play, Settings, How To Play]. One of the few things I need help with is to get music going and be able to switch it on and off with a segmented control in the [Settings Menu] and keep it on that stage when the actual game is running.

- Do I need a class for every view?
- In which view do I create the music?

Answer (score 0):

I would give you the advice to use for each view a class derived from UIViewController.
And then in your class `Settings` I would declare an UISegmentedControl that reacts on the user. If the user turn ON then just playing the music and when you do not release this UIViewController than the segemented control stays ON.